# MATLAB - Insert Rows Into A Much Larger Preallocated Zeros Matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to concatenate variable row but constant column data, vertically, into one "collection" matrix.

When dynamically expanding the collection matrix, I get slow performance (for obvious reasons). I want to preallocate this collection matrix (zero'd out), and then gradually overwrite the zeros with rows of new data. I usually do not know how many rows of data I'll have total, so I'll probably have to overshoot the matrix size and then trim down.

So, my question is, how does one go about doing this efficiently *AND* safely?

I currently preallocate a big 'ol collection matrix, and then keep a separate scalar variable called "myMatrixPtr". It points to the next free row. I then insert as such:

```
myMatrix(myMatrixPtr:(myMatrixPtr+numOfNewRows)-1, :) = newRowData;
```

It's very cumbersome and I'm worried that one morning I won't have my coffee, I mess this up, overwrite the wrong data, things explode, etc.

Is there a simpler way to do this? I do not want to insert rows, I want to use what I already have and allocate new large blocks if I have to. If, however, there's a better methodology I would love to hear it and learn.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you will find [this post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/) and [this post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance/) extremely interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's pretty much how you do it.  The only addition is that you actually don;t need to make your accumulation array that big to start, as long as you have a smart re-allocation scheme.  My favorite is usually to double the size when you run out of space.

A quick end-to-end implementation is below.

```
nCols = 4;
initSize = 1024;
ixNext = 1;

dataAccumulation = zeros(initSize, nCols);
collectionComplete = false;


while ~collectionComplete
    %Newly collected data
    newCollectedData = randn(ceil(rand*15),nCols);

    %Some row computations
    numOfNewRows = size(newCollectedData,1);
    ixLastInsertRow = ixNext+numOfNewRows-1;

    %Double the accumulation array if needed
    if size(dataAccumulation,1)<ixLastInsertRow
        dataAccumulation(size(dataAccumulation,1)*2,1)=0;
    end

    %Place the data and increment pointer
    dataAccumulation(ixNext:ixLastInsertRow, :) = newCollectedData;
    ixNext = ixLastInsertRow + 1;

    %Deterimine if we want to continue
    collectionComplete = (rand<0.001);
end

%Trim to size
dataAccumulation = dataAccumulation(1:(ixNext-1),:);
```

Comment: Incidentally, I learned the double memory size technique from this JoelOnSoftware article:  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html